# Using a splitter on an Iterated LinkedList?

Tags: java

Just wondering if you can use a splitter class to split up details moved from a LinkedList to and iterated one? This is the code of the initial split I used before I iterated the LinkedList:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("today.txt"));

        while (input.hasNextLine())
        { 
            names = input.nextLine();
            if(names.contains(":"))
                {
                    splitter2 = names.split(":");
                    name = splitter2[0];
                    times = splitter2[1];
                    System.out.printf("%s\t\t %s \n",name, times);

                }
            q1.add(names);  
        }
```

Q1 being the LinkedList that i have created. 
Is there anyway to split the iterated list so that i can only search for name when calling back the new Iterated List?

Comment: unclear what you are asking. why not only add "name" to the list instead of "names".

Comment: I would like to add both name and times, so names contains both.

Comment: are the names unique? then use a map having they key "name" and value "times"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, a Map would suit your needs better than a LinkedList.

You can have a `Map<String,String>` where the key is `name` and the value is `times`. Or you can have a `Map<String,SomeObject>` where the key is the name and the value some object that contains the data you read from the line.

Then, instead of `q1.add(names)`, you can have :

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
...
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    ...
    map.put (name,times);
    ...
}
```

or

```
Map<String,SomeObject> map = new HashMap<>();
...
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    ...
    map.put (name,new SomeObject(name,times);
    ...
}
```

Later you can search the map for a specific name (`map.containsKey(name)` or `map.get(name)`), or iterate over all the names (using `map.keySet()`).

Comment: All names are unique, but I was asked to use only LinkedLists. But I need the data split up so I can search through the List using only peoples names, instead of having to put in names and times.

Comment: @BamBam If you only need the names and you must use a LinkedList, just add `name` to the list (instead of `names`).

Answer (score 0):

This is a little unclear, but I think what you're looking for is a `HashMap`. If the idea is to put the names and times into a data structure so that you can later search by name, then you want a `HashMap<String,String> map`, and then

```
map.put(name,times);
```

to add to the map. Later on, you can retrieve the times for a particular name with

```
map.get(name);
```

There are some assumptions here:

1. You don't care about the *order* of the names (see `LinkedHashMap` if you do care).
2. The names are unique (see Guava's `Multimap` if they're not unique).

Comment: All names are unique, but I was asked to use only LinkedLists. But I need the data split up so I can search through the List using only peoples names, instead of having to put in names and times.

Comment: @BamBam in that case you need a new class that can store names and times, so that you can go through the list and ask each element what its name is.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `Class`, change `q1` to a list of this `type`, add the elements if they can be `split`.

```
final List<Person> q1=new LinkedList<Person>();

{...other code...}
//your code change to add to this list when split can occur  

if(names.contains(":"))
{
    splitter2 = names.split(":");
    name = splitter2[0];
    times = splitter2[1];
    System.out.printf("%s\t\t %s \n",name, times);
    q1.add(new Person(name,times); 
}
```

Then you can iterate the `list` and compare the attribute `name` with a `search key`:

```
final String searchKey="george";
for(final Person person : q1){
    if(person.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(searchKey))
       System.out.println("I found " + searchKey +"!");
}
```

Person class:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String time;

    public Person(String name, String time) {
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can iterate and split the String only `list`, during the iteration, in the same way you did before. The previous method is better.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String search = "george";
    List<String> q1 = new LinkedList<String>();
    q1.add("tom:120000");
    q1.add("george:130000");
    q1.add("john:120000");
    for (final String q : q1) { //for each string q in the list q1
        if (q.contains(":")) {
            final String[] split = q.split(":");
            final String name = split[0];
            final String time = split[1];
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(search)) {
                System.out.println("I found " + search + "!");
                System.out.println(name + " : " + time);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```